# How to post a tweet with an image to a website without including the URL in the tweet body?

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I used Feedburner to automatically tweet new posts on my blog, but Feedburner stopped working and I want to write my own code to do the same.

The Feedburner tweets looked [like this](https://twitter.com/FilmesNetflix/status/1131212179389198337): the post title followed by a short excerpt and a clickable image pointing to the blog post. The URL for the blog post is not included in the body of the tweet.

Can I do the same with the Twitter API, preferably using Python?

I've looked at the docs of both [python-twitter PostUpdate()](https://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/twitter.html#twitter.api.Api.PostUpdate) and [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update), but I could not achieve the same result. At most I could publish a tweet with the image, but without a link to the blog post.

```
# api_twitter = twitter.API( ...
msg = "My tweet message body."
img = "https://[...].jpg"
status = api_twitter.PostUpdate(status=msg, media=img)
```

Comment: That's using Twitter cards, where the target webpage includes metadata that defines the image to show. Check the documentation on this https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/abouts-cards.html

Comment: The URLs I post on Twitter are already optimized for cards. I've already seen the documentation you provided, but it doesn't say how to post a "Twitter card" using the Twitter API and achieving the same result as Feedburner (i.e., the card appearing in the tweet but without the URL appearing in the tweet body).

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem - I should NOT use the `media` parameter at all in the `PostUpdate()` call, and just let Twitter itself fetch all Card data from the URL I provided at the end of `status`. The Card will be displayed, but not the URL.